# Include Serilog sink requiring dependency before dependency injection in .NET Core

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, .net-core

Here is a rundown of the situation

- This is a .Net Core (2.1) application with a console and web front ends.
  *For simplicity this question focuses only on the console end although
  the web end has the same issues.*
- [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) is the logger of choice. We use 2 sinks (i.e. output sources): [Console](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console) and [MongoDB](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mongodb)
- Security is a concern - the MongoDB connection string contains the password so it needs to be fetched from a secure source. *Here we are using an custom created library to retrieve any sensitive information.*
- My understanding is that Serilog configurations are not mutable (for example, add/configure another sink) after initialization, but can be modified after the fact to some extent with "[enrichers](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment)". This is an aspect I am unfamiliar with.
- This solution is using [standard .NET dependency injection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

**What's a better way of setting up Serilog, where a sink has a dependency, in a solution using dependency injection?** Examples, patterns, templates are welcome. Most examples I've come across of Serilog with .NET Core DI don't address this situation.

```
public class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var secrets = new ThirdPartySecretProvider("MyApp.Console");
        var secretWrapper = new ThirdPartySecretProviderWrapper(secrets);
        var loggingConnectionString = GetLoggingConnectionString(secretsWrapper);

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.MongoDB(loggingConnectionString, "applicationLogs")
            .CreateLogger();

        SelfLog.Enable(System.Console.Error);

        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection, secretServerWrapper);
        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        try
        {
            var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<Application>();
            var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            Application app = new Application(logger, config);
            app.Run(args);
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }

    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, ISecretsWrapper secrets)
    {
        IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .Build();

        var mongoUsernameRead = config["MongoDB:ReadUsername"];
        var mongoClientRead = new DataAccess.Mongo.MongoClient(mongoUsernameRead, secrets.MongoReadPassword);
        services.AddSingleton<DataAccess.Mongo.IMongoClient>(mongoClientRead);

        var hadoopRepository = new HadoopRepository(secretServer.HadoopApiKey);
        services.AddSingleton<IHadoopRepository>(hadoopRepository);

        services
            .AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog(dispose: true))
            .AddSingleton(config)
            .AddSingleton<ISecretsWrapper>(secrets)
            .AddSingleton<IFileHelper, FileHelper>()
            .AddSingleton<IRepositoryMongo, RepositoryMongo>()
            .AddSingleton<IServiceMongo, ServiceMongo>()
            .AddSingleton<IBaseHttpClient, BaseHttpClient>()
            // ... additional dependencies omitted
    }

    private static string GetLoggingConnectionString(ISecretsWrapper secrets)
    {
        var mongoUsernameReadWrite = "app_myAppReadWrite";
        var mongoClientLog = new DataAccess.Mongo.MongoClient(mongoUsernameReadWrite, secrets.MongoReadWritePassword);
        return mongoClientLog.MongoConnectionString;
    }

}
```

Related examples:

- Writeup by nblumhardt, <s>a major Serilog contributor</s> creator of Serilog 
  https://nblumhardt.com/2017/08/use-serilog/
- Clean example with some a sink other than console https://jacksowter.net/serilog-config/
- [Stack Overflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477415/how-can-i-reconfigure-serilog-without-restarting-the-application) of creating multiple loggers at startup
- [Vanilla DI with .NET Core from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707534.aspx)

One potential change is to create a simple logger (using Serilogger or other) initially to capture failures before the application proper gets started, then create the desired logger to use for the rest of the application. **What are the considerations of this approach?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is being discussed on the [Serilog integration for ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/141) repository. Nicholas Blumhardt has proposed a [draft](https://gist.github.com/nblumhardt/34c0c273c383da9745f4e974f12b9cac) for a *late init sink* that would be used like this:

```
var signalRSink = new LateInitSink();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Sink(signalRSink)
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("Sadly, nobody will get this");

// ... resolve that hub ...
signalRSink.Init(wt => wt.Console());

Log.Information("Ah so nice to be loggin' again");
```

The final version is not yet implemented. Quoting Nicholas Blumhardt from the aforementioned issue:

> Yes, it's still being considered - just a matter of someone finding the time to dig in deeply/write some code. Cheers!